# Isometric deformation of a helicoid with $n$ turns

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Given a helicoid, $\mathcal{H}$, of pitch $P$ with $n$ turns, where
$$n = \dfrac{L}{P},$$
can I not isometrically deform $\mathcal{H}$ into a helicoid with just one turn by varying the length $L$ of the axis so as to keep $P$ fixed. The fundamental forms are all dependent on $P$ only, so the resulting surfaces will be congruent. But by varying $L$, am I not stretching and thus disturbing the arc length element? This is probably a nonsensical observation or I am missing something simple. I wanted to verify however.

Comment: The two helicoids you described certainly cannot be congruent. I do not believe the first and second fundamental forms depend only on $P$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the response. For a helicoid with corodinates $u,v$, the first fundamental forms are $1,0,1+P^2u^2$ and the second forms are $0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+P^2}}, 0$. Am I right?

Comment: I think you should have $P^2+u^2$, but the presence of $u$ here makes your statement dubious. Write down the transformation you have in mind in terms of $u,v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for responding again. $P^2+u^2$ works too I think I should have written $1+\frac{u^2}{P^2}$. But then I can just effect the change from the former to the latter by taking $u' = u/P$, right?? And after that, I just had in mind the trivial isometry $ u'=u$ and $v'=v$. Forgive me if I have made a trivial mistake.

Comment: That is the identity map. That doesn't do anything. I think your second fund. form won't be right if you change coords as you said.

Comment: You can’t ignore the $u$ in these formulas. You have to tell me the mapping you've described with your words. It is most definitely not the identity.

Comment: @TedShifrin. I think I sort of understand the point you are trying to drive home. For a helicoid with $n$ turns of length $L$ and say width $2a$, the coordinates $u \in [-a,a] $ and $v \in [0,L]$, so in the change I mention, $v \in [0,L']$ and so the new coordinates will be scaled, is that fine??So I will be getting something like $u' = ku$ and $v' = bv$. This essentially amounts to a reparametrization then?

Comment: Well, see if that's what you described. The map goes from one portion of the helicoid to a different portion of it? That is no congruence.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I think I can see that now. Would it be better to say they are similar? But I reckon it would still be a local isometry? As a crude analogue, this would be akin to saying that both $(\cos{x}, \sin{x)}$ and $(\cos{2x}, \sin{2x})$ would be parametrisations of the unit circle, right?? Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: Sounds right, if that's what in fact the mapping is.